Are there any security risks by adding the program IDL in client side code?
I don't really see any inherit risk by doing this, but maybe I am being naive.
If it is dangerous or a potential vulnerability, please let me know why.
thanks <3

No. The IDL just gives you an easy way to parse what data is stored and what instructions exist for an onchain program. If you have some data/instruction in there that is security critical and you don't want people to know about, not publicizing the IDL might deter attackers for a little while longer, but in the end they'll find the vulnerability anyway.
What it will do though is make people appreciate you for giving them an easier way to parse your onchain program :).

Note that I mention "publicizing" instead of "client side code". At the end of the day it's the same, since anyone can just e.g. "inspect element" your client side code to extract it. I assume you already know this else you wouldn't be asking, but for other future readers of this answer it might be good to know.

Thanks so much! :)
Relatively new to deploying full-functioning on chain applications, so this is greatly appreciated.
